# How can I retrigger the same jenkins build again

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I am connected between **jenkins** and **gerrit** successfully. The gerrit trigger is on every new change. Sometimes the build is not started (no matter what is the reason).

How can I start the exact same build by passing a variable from gerrit?
I want to clone exactly the same changes as they are pushed to gerrit.

For now I can start the build with this command:

```
curl -u user:password jenkins_url/job/job_name/build?token
```

Is there a way to start this build with gerrit param?

For example

```
curl -u user:password jenkins_url/job/job_name/build?token param=change-id
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can trigger a build passing a parameter with the following command:

```
curl -u USER:PASS "https://JENKINS-SERVER/JOB-PATHNAME/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&PARAM-NAME-1=PARAM-VALUE-1&PARAM-NAME2=PARAM-VALUE-2"
```

Comment: Have you used the double quotes in the Jenkins URL? Check if all "?" and the "&" characters are correct. Check the parameters names and values too.